# Add $_POST value to PHP array with every AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

```
var itemtotal = parseFloat(words[1]).toFixed(2.0)*qty;

            $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'cartitem.php',
            data: {itemtotal:itemtotal},
            success: function(data){

                alert(data);

            }
```

I want to add the value from each AJAX call to a PHP array for later processing. How can I do that?

Comment: <?php

$orderitems = [];
array_push($orderitems,$_POST['itemtotal']);

echo array_sum($orderitems);



?>

Comment: If you want to maintain the values from theses post requests over multiple ajax calls, you will have to store them in either a server side database, client side local storage, or in a temporary fashion, possibly by concatenating the values into a DOM element (e.g. hidden input box)

Comment: There's multiple ways to do that, I guess $_SESSION will be your friend here. All depends on what you really want to do with the values.

Answer (score 0):

php :

```
if (isset($_POST['itemtotal'])) 
{

$array = [];

if (is_numeric($_POST['itemtotal'])) { 
//you need to do some validation here its just an example
 array_push($array, $_POST['itemtotal']);
}
}
```

hope it helps